# How to substract two string columns in pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I want to subtract `column1 - column2`, i.e. remove all substrings matched in `column2` from `column1` and put the result in new column `result`.

pyspark data frame:

```
+--+-------------------------+--------------------------+--------------+
|ID|           column1       |   column2                | result       |
+--+-------------------------+--------------------------+--------------+
|1 | Hi how are you fine but | Hi I am fine how about u | are you but  |
|2 | javascript python XML   | python XML               | javascript   |
|3 | include all the inform  | include inform           | all the      |
+--+-------------------------+--------------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: not matched string from column2 moved over to result..apologies for the confusion.

Comment: @blackbishop                                                                                                                       ```                                                                                                                                      not matched string from column2 moved over to result..apologies for the confusion         ```

Comment: @Blackbishop - I'm sorry late reply actually you answered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array_except`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#array_except) to remove from `column1` all substrings present in `colmun2`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = df.withColumn(
    "result",
    F.array_join(
        F.array_except(F.split("column1", " "), F.split("column2", " ")),
        " "
    )
)

df1.show(truncate=False)

#+---+-----------------------+------------------------+-----------+
#|ID |column1                |column2                 |result     |
#+---+-----------------------+------------------------+-----------+
#|1  |Hi how are you fine but|Hi I am fine how about u|are you but|
#|2  |javascript python XML  |python XML              |javascript |
#|3  |include all the inform |include inform          |all the    |
#+---+-----------------------+------------------------+-----------+
```